# How does a Pandas DataFrame interpret two given columns?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've got the following statement:

```
apps[group_indexes]['reader'].notnull()
```

`[group_indexes]` is a Series full of booleans, whereas `['reader']` is an actual column within the apps DataFrame. How do the two interact? I know `group_indexes` can't be referring to an actual column within the DataFrame, but I'm not clear on how it's interacting with the `['reader']` column.

Comment: The `group_indexes` filter to the rows that are True within the Series. So `apps[group_indexes]` will return **all** columns of the DataFrame, but only a subset of the rows. Adding the `['reader']` will make it return only the 'reader' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that `[group_indexes]` filters the `app` dataframe as a boolean mask.  Essentially it only returns rows of the `app` dataframe where `[group_indexes]` is `True`.

From that filtered dataframe, the `[reader]` column is then selected for application of the `.notnull()` method.

Answer (score 1):

> How do the two interact?

As consecutive operations.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

> dfmi['one']['second']
>
> dfmi['one'] selects the first level of the columns and returns a data
> frame that is singly-indexed. Then another python operation
> dfmi_with_one['second'] selects the series indexed by 'second'
> happens. This is indicated by the variable dfmi_with_one because
> pandas sees these operations as separate events. e.g. separate calls
> to **getitem**, so it has to treat them as linear operations, they
> happen one after another.